# Running a Let's Chat server - Exception due to legacy binary "node" (for node.js)

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm trying to get a [Let's Chat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEIQFjAHahUKEwiIn9-at5XHAhXJlYgKHexXCf4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsdelements.github.io%2Flets-chat%2F&ei=r9XDVciLKcmrogTsr6XwDw&usg=AFQjCNHx7YUL5rCezS7-L32_JyH4OW486g&sig2=T6MjT1dSA0MX5IUZ34Qi1A&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cGU) server up and running on a Google Compute instance running Ubuntu 14. I'm hitting an exception when trying to run the `npm start` command to get the server going, here's the error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

This is frustrating because I definitely have `nodejs-legacy` installed, which it's my understanding is designed to get rid of this error. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Can you post the output of `node -v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB was not running.  My mistake. For those who run into this error and stumble upon this page, make sure to run `mongod` in a `screen` to prevent this exception.

Cheers.